# How can I count the characters in a word document?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-word-2003, microsoft-word-2010

well I looked at the similar Qs but they were all about counting words not characters, is there a way to do this? or if not Are there any plug-ins for this purpose?

Comment: The word count window shows character count as well (Word 2007).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Word 2010 and 2007, to get to the word count window you click on "Words: ###" At the bottom of every document.

This Window then shows you the various word and character counts.

This can also be found under the 'Review' tab.

[image]

In Word 2003 you need to go to Tools > Word Count and the Word Count window then appears.

[image]

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way to count characters in a word (or any other document) is to copy and paste it into an online character counter tool like http://www.charactercountonline.com